# PHP MySQL Update minus variable without separate SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know there is a way to do this. Basically I have the variable `$amount` and want to take that away from the column amount in the table stock.

The problem is I normally run a select query find out the value then deduct the variable and run another update query.

What is the syntax to run a single update that will just minus the value.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's as simple as it seems. Parentheses are optional in this example.  Be sure to use the appropriate condition in your `WHERE` clause!

```
$qry = "UPDATE table SET column = (column - $amount) WHERE somecondition;";
```

The variable `$amount` is assumed to be properly escaped already, according to the MySQL API you are using, or better yet, a parameter to a prepared example, as in PDO:

```
$qry = "UPDATE table SET column = (column - :amount) WHERE somecondition;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute(array(':amount' => $amount));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET amount = amount - $amount WHERE primary_key = value LIMIT 1
```

If you want to make sure `amount` doesn't go below zero:

```
UPDATE table_name SET amount = amount - $amount WHERE primary_key = value AND amount >= $amount LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want below?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET amount = amount -$amount
WHERE primary = id
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity are you getting $variable from some other sql select?  Like perhaps a parts list or something? It could potentially be much faster to run the entire thing inside a stored procedure or compound select.

If that $variable is static or locally generated disregard.

Comment: ah, in that cause +1 for michael